# Updated Python from disk image, want to make it available in terminal

Tags: python

I have Python 2.6.1 which came on the Mac I have, but I'd recently downloaded and installed the disk image of 3.1.3 and I'd like to have it available in Terminal, how can I do this?  For instance when I do `$ python -V` in Terminal I get 2.6.1.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Python 3 versions are installed with the symlink name `python3`.  Try:

```
$ python3 -V
```

Answer (score 1):

The default Python version in Mac OS X needs to stay the default Python version, or things will break. You want to install it alongside with Python 2. This is most likely exactly what happened, but you start Python 3 with `python3`.

Comment: The python.org installers for any version of Python take care of all that and never disturb the Apple-supplied system Python(s).

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not a Mac user, so I don't know a couple of specifics (default PATH, etc).

Also, a bit of clarity - when you use the installer, it lets you customize the installation to install in a specific location - do you know where that is. If you didn't select a location, it defaults to /usr/local/bin.

From Terminal, try "python3".  If that fails, try "/usr/local/bin/python3".

Outside of that, wherever it's found, you'll want that in your path statement if it isn't there already.

It's not recommended that you "replace" the system python with python 3.x, as you'll definitely have problems.

Comment: The python.org installers for Mac OS X install pythons in a special framework configuration that allows multiple co-existing versions.  They do not overwrite the system python.  By default they install symlinks from /usr/local/bin but also modify your shell startup files to put the appropriate framework `bin` folder first in the shell search `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaim** : i'm talking Linux (Ubuntu) here , hopefully Mac have something similarity.

if you want to make /usr/bin/python symlink to python3 rather than python2.6 , here is what you can do :

type this in the command line:

```
$ update-alternatives --config python
```

you should see something similar to this :

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3     20        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python2.6   10        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

now just choose the right python version.

N.B : if the first command fail with something like this :

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python
```

then add all the python version before continuing like this:

```
$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.6 10
$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 20
```

Comment: There is nothing like that on OS X and it is a bad idea to modify its `/usr/bin/python` or anything else in `/usr/bin` as those files are managed by Apple as part of OS X.

Comment: @Ned Deily: Actually the method that i pointed above is very useful and it not dangerous at all, because __/usr/bin/python__ is just a symlink (at least in unix), changing the python symlink is just like changing any symlink that reside in /usr/bin which are there for many purpose , another example is __/usr/bin/x-www-browser__ this symlink is used by application to know the default web browser, so if you want to change the default web browser you change this symbolic link, another one is __/usr/bin/editor__ default text editor ... , so they are just symlinks :)

Comment: That's true on some platforms but it is not the case on Mac OS X which is what the OP was asking about.  In fact, on OS X 10.6, which is what the OP is running, `/usr/bin/python` is a program not a symlink and you should definitely not overwrite it.  It is unwise to generalize about *unix* systems; there are many variations.